# SQL query for 3 rows with the min date, particular file extensions

Tags: sql, oracle

In the table

```
CREATE TABLE "FILES"
(
"ID_FILE" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"REPORT_DATE" DATE,
"NAME" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
"PROCESSED" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) 
)
```

There are records with different dates, names that end on 'p1', 'l1', 'm1' and whether they are processed or not - 'N' and 'Y' respectively. 
I want to choose from the earliest date, unprocessed files, package of these 3 names that end of 'p1', 'l1', 'm1'.
Oracle  query:

```
SELECT REPORT_DATE, DISTINCT NAME 
FROM 
( SELECT * 
  FROM FILES)
WHERE 
( NAME LIKE '%p1' OR 
NAME LIKE '%l1' OR 
NAME LIKE '%m1') AND 
ROWNUM = 3 AND 
PROCESSED = 'N'
GROUP BY REPORT_DATE
HAVING MIN(REPORT_DATE);
```

The error is :

```
Error at Line: 12 Column: 23 (having clause)
```

**Edit:**

the records are like :

```
(1, '11/05/2011', 'some_name_p1', 'N')
(2, '11/05/2011', 'some_name_l1', 'N')
(3, '11/05/2011', 'some_name_m1', 'N')  

(4, '11/05/2011', 'some_name_k1', 'Y')
(5, '11/05/2012', 'some_name_p1', 'n')
(6, '11/05/2011', 'some_name_m1', 'N')
```

The query should select only the first 3 rows(1,2,3), nothing more. These 3 rows, must  contain all three 'p1', 'l1', 'm1' extensions in the names.

Comment: First of all your query has few errors - DISTINCT clause can't be appplied to separate column, but just to the tulpe completely. ROWNUM = 3 will always return no rows. And as it was said before - please provide the data and desirable result.

Answer (score 0):

A `HAVING` clause is typically used for comparisons with aggregate functions. What you are probably looking for is to match the `REPORT_DATE` with the minimum value, which you can use a sub query for:

```
SELECT
    REPORT_DATE, DISTINCT NAME 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM FILES)
WHERE 
    (NAME LIKE '%p1' OR 
    NAME LIKE '%l1' OR 
    NAME LIKE '%m1')
    AND ROWNUM = 3
    AND PROCESSED = 'N'
    AND REPORT_DATE = (SELECT MIN(REPORT_DATE) FROM FILES WHERE NAME LIKE '%p1' OR NAME LIKE '%l1' OR NAME LIKE '%m1')
GROUP BY
    REPORT_DATE;
```

Comment: You forgot to get MIN(REPORT_DATE) in context of one file (I assume due to the use of distinct)-I mean you should do it with correlated subquery because @Bor need minimum date per file not per all files. `SELECT
    REPORT_DATE, NAME 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM FILES) outerFile
WHERE 
    (NAME LIKE '%p1' OR 
    NAME LIKE '%l1' OR 
    NAME LIKE '%m1')
    AND ROWNUM = 3
    AND PROCESSED = 'N'
    AND REPORT_DATE = (SELECT MIN(REPORT_DATE) FROM FILES innerFile WHERE NAME LIKE '%p1' OR NAME LIKE '%l1' OR NAME LIKE '%m1' and innerFile.id_file = outerFile.id_file)
GROUP BY
  REPORT_DATE;`

Comment: AND ROWNUM = 3 - this will cause 0 rows always.